# CSS картинки и графика?

Tags: html, css

Есть задача, чтобы картинка подгонялась под размер окна. Нужно, чтобы либо картинка адекватно подгонялась в окно, либо картинка оставалась статичной, а все остальное - подгонялось. Хочу сразу сказать, что картинка - что-то вроде фона, на котором изображены некие узлы, и у этих узлов должно быть значение.

[image: CSS картинки и графика?]

Что-то вроде этого. Это сложно реализовать с помощью html и css?

в общем есть нижняя область - пусть будет фиксирована по высоте. растягивается на всю ширину окна. все что выше - это картика, тоже растягивается на всю остальную часть. но у картинки есть подписи. и они должны соответствовать определенным координатам.
грубо говоря вот есть

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

изменили окно - поменялась картинка и расположение подписи. график все так же той же высоты и растянут на всю ширину

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта как решить это

```
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* Для хрома */
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Для лисы*/
-o-background-size: cover;  /* Для оперы*/
-ms-background-size: cover;  /* Для ИЭ*/
background-size: cover;  /* Для закрипления*/
```

или

```
background-size: 100% 100%; /* Для всех браузеров */
```

Comment: нет эт тупо сделает фоном.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю позиционирование в % в купе с пропорциональным изменением размера изображения спасет ситуацию.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?